# How to set state while testing React component using Enzyme

Tags: reactjs, unit-testing, jestjs, enzyme

I am testing a React Component. My state is -

```
constructor(props){
 super(props);
 this.state = {
  data:{
   name: "",
  },
 isActive: false,
 }
}
```

in my test file, I want to set the name state to some value like -

```
test("should change the state to Active when user changes the status from Inactive", () => {
wrapper.setState({
  isActive:true,
  data:{ name:"Jim" },
});
expect(wrapper.state("data").name).toBe("Jim");
)};
```

Here, I am able to access the state using `wrapper.state("data").name` this line. But using setState (mentioned in the test) it gives me error -

> TypeError: e.value.replace is not a function

So I want to know is how to set the state of the name key.

Comment: where is this coming from `e.value.replace `?

Comment: I am not passing any event. Just calling the setState method. @RedBaron

Comment: there some code in your component which execute some function depends on state. Or it could be a HOC or router issue. Are you using mount or shallow?

Comment: All I want to know is how to set state in the data key while writing the test

Comment: well you're doing it the correct way but clearly something is conflicting somewhere else in your code

Comment: ```wrapper.setState({
  isActive:true,
  data:{ ...wrapper.state.data, name:"Jim" }
});```

Comment: Not working @demkovych

Comment: setState is asynchronous function. You need to add some timeout or delay which will allow your state to update.

Comment: Then it should throw the error while I am trying to access the state, right? But here, It is giving me an error while setting it. @demkovych

Comment: your test is correct. A problem with something else.